# Display Custom taxonomy, Child terms and posts in a template Under Specific Parent terms

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I want to Display Custom taxonomy, Child terms and posts in a template Under Specific Parent terms.

I need is this:

**Parent Taxonomy Term**

**-- Child Taxonomy Term**

**--- Post Type**

**--- Post Type**

**--- Post Type**

Answer (score 0):

This is the working code.
You can try with yours

```
                $id = get_the_ID(false);
                $categories = get_the_category();
                $parents = array();
                $childs = array();
                foreach($categories as $cat){
                    if($cat->parent == 0){
                        $parents[] = $cat;
                    } else {
                        $childs[] = $cat;
                    }
                }
                $i = 1;
                echo "<div class='sub-container'>";
                foreach($parents as $parent){
                    if($i>3){
                        $i=1;
                        echo "<div class='clr'></div>";
                        echo "<hr class='mt25'>";
                        echo "<div class='one3 gray-text mar-none'>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<div class='one3 gray-text'>";
                    }

                    echo "<h3 class='title fs14'>".$parent->name."</h3>";
                    echo "<div class='fs10'>";
                    foreach($childs as $child){
                        if($child->parent == $parent->cat_ID){
                            echo "<div class='fs14 child-cat'><a href=".get_category_link( $child->cat_ID).">" . $child->name . "</a></div>";
                        }
                    }
                    echo "</div></div>";
                    $i++;
                }
                echo '</div>';
```

Comment: Please correct your markup. Do not post text as code. Text is text, not code